# Filters rows in a table with foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables Customers and Hobbies. Both are linked to each other by a CUST_ID column. 
I want to get customer information who are having hobbies as only 'Books' and 'Playing' but not any other hobby.

Sample table and excepted result

```
+--------+------------+
|CUST_ID | CUST_NAME  |
+--------|------------+
| 1      |  John      |
| 2      |  Roy       |
| 3      |  ben       |
+---------------------+

+--------+------------+---------+
|HOB_ID  | HOB_NAME   | CUST_ID |
+--------|------------+---------+
| 1      |  Books     |   1     |
| 2      |  Playing   |   1     |
| 3      |  Books     |   2     |
| 4      |  Playing   |   2     |
| 5      |  Singing   |   2     |
| 6      |  Books     |   3     |
| 7      |  Singing   |   3     |
+---------------------+---------+
```

Output should be - 1 John. Because I want to fetch only customers which are having their hobbies as Books and playing only.

Comment: `oracle` and `sql-server` are two different `RDBMS`. Please tag the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listagg()` is one way to handle this:

```
select h.cust_id, c.cust_name
from customer c join
     hobbies h
     on c.cust_id = h.cust_id
group by h.cust_id, c.cust_name
having listagg(h.hob_name, ',') within group (order by h.hob_name) = 'books,playing';
```

Comment: listtag supports in Oracle ? I need specifically for oracle. Sorry for tagging mysl-server

Comment: @software_guy . . . Yes, of course.  I think Oracle invented the function.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be

```
SQL> with
  2  customer (cust_id, cust_name) as
  3    (select 1, 'John' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'Roy'  from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'Ben'  from dual
  6    ),
  7  hobbies (hob_id, hob_name, cust_id) as
  8    (select 1, 'books'  , 1 from dual union all
  9     select 2, 'playing', 1 from dual union all
 10     select 3, 'books'  , 2 from dual union all
 11     select 4, 'playing', 2 from dual union all
 12     select 5, 'singing', 2 from dual union all
 13     select 6, 'books'  , 3 from dual union all
 14     select 7, 'singing', 3 from dual
 15    )
 16  select h.cust_id, c.cust_name
 17  from hobbies h join customer c on c.cust_id = h.cust_id
 18  group by h.cust_id, c.cust_name
 19  having count(distinct h.hob_name) = 2  --> 2 hobbies
 20    and min(h.hob_name) = 'books'        --> one is "books"
 21    and max(h.hob_name) = 'playing'      --> another is "playing"
 22  /

   CUST_ID CUST
---------- ----
         1 John

SQL>
```

Lines #1 - 15 represent sample data; you have that and don't type it. Query you need begins at line #16; see comments.

---

If if turns out that you want to find someone who has different number of hobbies whose list **must** match the search hobbies list, then you could use a function, e.g.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_cnt (par_cust_id in number, par_srch in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    l_cnt number;
  5    l_dis number;
  6  begin
  7    -- number of distinct hobbies per PAR_CUST_ID
  8    select count(distinct hob_name)
  9      into l_dis
 10      from hobbies
 11      where cust_id = par_cust_id;
 12
 13    -- number of hobbies per PAR_CUST_ID that match ("intersect") list of
 14    -- hobbies passed as the search PAR_SRCH string
 15    select count(*)
 16      into l_cnt
 17      from (select hob_name
 18              from hobbies
 19              where cust_id = par_cust_id
 20            intersect
 21            select trim(regexp_substr(par_srch, '[^,]+', 1, level))
 22              from dual
 23              connect by level <= regexp_count(par_srch, ',') + 1
 24           );
 25    -- function returns "1" only if everything matches
 26    return case when l_cnt = regexp_count(par_srch, ',') + 1 and
 27                     l_cnt = l_dis
 28                     then 1
 29                else 0
 30           end;
 31  end f_cnt;
 32  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Let's do some testing:

```
SQL> select cust_name from customer where f_cnt(cust_id, 'books,singing') = 1;

CUST
----
Ben

SQL> select cust_name from customer where f_cnt(cust_id, 'playing,singing') = 1;

no rows selected

SQL> select cust_name from customer where f_cnt(cust_id, 'playing,books,singing') = 1;

CUST
----
Roy

SQL> select cust_name from customer where f_cnt(cust_id, 'reading') = 1;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: If the table has million rows?

Comment: Millions of hobbies? *Software guy* will have problem in finding someone manually to say which result they wanted.

Comment: @Mushariar What do you mean by table has million rows? Littlefoot has given a demo and used the `WITH` clause to build sample data and clearly mentioned it in the answer. And I don't understand **what is this fantasy about** `million/billion of rows`? **Number of rows are meaningless without any context in database**.

Comment: In future If I want to add more hobbies while filtering let say I want to 2 more hobbies to my filter condition then how do I do that?

Comment: @Littlefoot *Millions of hobbies? Software guy will have problem in finding someone manually to say which result they wanted.* LOL, good one :-)

Comment: @software_guy So you maintain the data in `oracle` and `sql-server` databases together by keeping them in sync?

Comment: Yes agreed. Actually what I meant is the demo code is written all customers row by row which might confuse newbies. Sorry if I have misinterpreted.

Comment: @software_guy: I added some more info about *more hobbies*. Have a look, please.

Comment: @Mushariar No problem, I understand you might have been confused initially looking at the rows in the WITH clause if it's new to you :-) Stay safe!

Comment: @Littlefoot I have tried the 1st query which you gave with min and max and it is working. But I tried the second query with only Books and Playing and it is not working. How do I make your second query work with any no.of hobbies? I mean if I want filter 1 hobby, 2 hoobies, 3 , 4 etc...

Comment: For the 2nd query: you'll have to fix values in lines #18 (list of hobbies) and #20 (number of hobbies).

Comment: @Littlefoot **Not Working**. Yeah I changed the distinct count to 2 and hobbies to playing and Books but it is not returning customers which are having only those

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm suggesting another approach, with a function. See if it helps.